# How to disable submit button until validation passed in specific field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form. In the form, I have a field calles sitename. If the user enters a sitename which is already in the database, it will show the message "That name is already in use" and give some suggestions. Up to this point, it works. But what I want, is to hide the submit button until the user enters a valid value to that field.

Here is my code:

form.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sitename").keyup(function() {
            var sitename = $('#sitename').val();
            if(sitename=="")
                {
                $("#disp").html("");
            }

            else
                {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "check_name.php",
                    data: "sitename="+ sitename ,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#disp").html(html);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
<button class="btn btn-1 btn-fill" type="submit" id="btn-signup" name="btn-signup">Submit</button>
</div>
```

check_name.php:

```
include('dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['sitename']))
{
    $sitename=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sitename']);
    $query=mysql_query("select * from template_users where sitename='$sitename'");
    $row=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($row==0)
    {
        /*echo "<span style='color:white;'>Available</span>";*/
    }
    else
    {

        $msg = $sitename.rand ( 1 , 10000 );
        $msg1 = $sitename.rand ( 1 , 100 );

        echo "<span style='color:antiquewhite;' ><b>Already exist please Use different Site Name such as<br/> $msg<br/>$msg1<br/><b/></span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: *"what i want is to hide the submit button"* - So, um, maybe the .hide() method? Then call .show() from your Ajax success handler if the entered value is OK?

Comment: What have you tried so far - as in, what do you expect that code to do, and how do you want it to work differently?

Comment: Additionally, don't use `mysql_` format methods. This library is deprecated, will be removed in future PHP versions and is unsafe - it could lead to loss of user data or damage to your system. If you're just learning PHP, start with http://www.phptherightway.com/ and don't look back!

Comment: You can disable/enable the button through Javascript or jQuery, as @nnnnnn suggested. However, keep in mind that any person on your website may re-enable the button and still submit the form so you should be prepared for that eventuality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sitename").keyup(function() {
            var sitename = $('#sitename').val();
            if(sitename=="")
            {
                $("#disp").html("");
            }

            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "check_name.php",
                    data: "sitename="+ sitename ,
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html != 'success')
                        {
                             $("#disp").html(html);
                             $("#btn-signup").hide();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             $("#btn-signup").show();
                        }
                    },

                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-1 btn-fill" type="submit" id="btn-signup" name="btn-signup" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
</div>
```

And in your check_name.php

```
<?php

include('dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['sitename']))
{
    $sitename=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sitename']);
    $query=mysql_query("select * from template_users where sitename='$sitename'");
    $row=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($row==0)
    {
        echo "success"; 
    }
    else
    {

        $msg = $sitename.rand ( 1 , 10000 );
        $msg1 = $sitename.rand ( 1 , 100 );

        echo "<span style='color:antiquewhite;' ><b>Already exist please Use different Site Name such as<br/> $msg<br/>$msg1<br/><b/></span>";
    }
    die;
}

?>
```

Comment: thank you very much this is working nicely.but there is a little problem.eventhough i eneterd none exist sitename in that field it still displays that message.can you help on this.
problem is when first time data is invalid message comes.but when i done it as suggested it still shows the message there

Comment: use `$("#disp").html("");` in ajax success else condition just above this line `$("#btn-signup").show();`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to keep track on the outcome of your PHP script. 
Change your code to:

**PHP**

```
<?php

include('dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['sitename']))
{
    $sitename=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sitename']); 
    $query=mysql_query("select * from template_users where sitename='$sitename'"); 
    $row=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($row==0)
    {

        echo json_encode([ "status" => 1, "html" => "<span style='color:white;'>Available</span>" ]);
    }
    else
    {

        $msg = $sitename.rand ( 1 , 10000 );
        $msg1 = $sitename.rand ( 1 , 100 );
        echo json_encode([ "status" => 0, "html" => "<span style='color:antiquewhite;' ><b>Already exist please Use different Site Name such as<br/> $msg<br/>$msg1<br/><b/></span>" ]);    
    }
}

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn-signup").hide();
        $("#sitename").keyup(function () {
            $("#btn-signup").hide(); 
            var sitename = $('#sitename').val();            
            if (sitename == "")
            {
                $("#disp").html("");
            }

            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "check_name.php",
                    data: "sitename=" + sitename,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.status == 1) {
                            $("#btn-signup").show();
                        }
                        $("#disp").html(result.html);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-1 btn-fill" type="submit" id="btn-signup" name="btn-signup">Submit</button>
</div>
```

That is, hide the button on start, if a user enters something, hide the button and wait till the text is validated. If it is valid, show it. If the user changes the text, then the button will be hidden again.

Please note:

1) `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since version 5.5 and have been removed in version 7. This on its own is enough indication that you need to move on and use something more secure and actively supported.

2) `mysql_real_escape_string` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` are not safe since they don't reliably consider server encoding. If you want to be safe, use real prepared statements (i.e. prepared statements which are prepared on the MySQL server).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use json to return the data like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "html"  : "<span style='color:antiquewhite;' ><b>Already exist please Use different Site Name such as<br/> $msg<br/>$msg1<br/><b/></span>"
}
```

and here's the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    /** Hide the button first */
    $('button').hide();

    $('#sitename').on('input', function()
    {
        var sitename = $('#sitename').val();

        if(sitename == '')
        {
            $("#disp").html("");
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type    : "POST",
                dataType: "json"
                url     : "check_name.php",
                data    : "sitename=" + sitename ,
                success : function(data)
                {
                    /** When the data is invalid */
                    if(data.status === 'error')
                    {
                        $('button').hide();
                        $("#disp").html(data.html);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('button').show();
                        /** Hide the html when the data is valid */
                        $("#disp").html('');
                    }
                },
            });
        }
    })
});
```

And your php code:

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

if(isset($_POST['sitename']))
{
    $sitename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sitename']);
    $query    = mysql_query("select * from template_users where sitename='$sitename'");
    $row      = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($row == 0)
    {
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'success',
                          'html'   => "<span style='color:white;'>Available</span>"]);
    }
    else
    {
        $msg  = $sitename.rand ( 1 , 10000 );
        $msg1 = $sitename.rand ( 1 , 100 );

        echo json_encode(['status' => 'error',
                          'html'   => "<span style='color:antiquewhite;' ><b>Already exist please Use different Site Name such as<br/> $msg<br/>$msg1<br/><b/></span>"]);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you very  much this is working nicely.but there is a little problem.eventhough i eneterd none exist sitename in that field it still displays that message.can you help on this.

Comment: don't you want to show the message when the data is invalid?

Comment: i wants to show.but the problem is when first time data is invalid message comes.but when i done it as suggested it still shows the message there

Comment: Edited, please check the javascript part, 

I just added a `$("#disp").html('');` to remove the html when the data is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
                  $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "check_name.php",
                        data: "sitename="+ sitename ,
                        success: function(html){
                            if(html !== "") {
                              $("#btn-signu").attr("disabled", true);
                            }
                            else {
                              $("#btn-signu").removeAttr("disabled");
                            }

                            $("#disp").html(html);

                        }
                    });
```

Check the html param in success callback function.

Answer (score 0):

In form.php change Javascript to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //get the button by its ID
        var $button = $('#btn-signup');
        $("#sitename").keyup(function() {

            //hide the button always
            $button.hide();

            var sitename = $('#sitename').val();
            if(sitename=="")
            {
                $("#disp").html("");
            }

            else
            {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "check_name.php",
                    data: "sitename="+ sitename ,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#disp").html(html);

                        if(!html.length){
                            //show the submit button if no error html
                            $button.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Button should be initial hidden. If the field can be prefilled, you need to check if the value is not empty before hiding the button.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
   <button class="btn btn-1 btn-fill" type="submit" id="btn-signup" name="btn-signup" style="display:none">Submit</button>
</div>
```